# How to query related objects with nhibernate using contains

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate

I'm rather new to NHibernate, so this one should be easy:

```
    public IList<Ad> Search(string query)
    {
        return unitOfWork.Session
            .QueryOver<Ad>()
            .JoinQueryOver<AdProperty>(x => x.Properties)
                .Where(ad => ad.Value.Contains(query))
            .List();
    }
```

What I am trying to do, of course, is to search for Ads, where the AdProperty Contains a certain string, and pass back the corresponding Ad objects as a result. (I realize this will not result in an optimal query, but for now this will suffice)

**The problem**

I cannot use .Contains, as it is unrecognized. So how would I do this correctly with NHibernate ?

I've had a look at [NHibernate query looking for the related object's related object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2620589/nhibernate-query-looking-for-the-related-objects-related-object), but I was unable to get that to function.

**Note**

I am using NHibernate 3.0+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more fiddling, I got the example (referenced above) to work. I will leave my solution for future reference for others.

```
    public IList<Ad> Search(string query)
    {
        return unitOfWork.Session
            .CreateCriteria<Ad>()
            .CreateAlias("Properties", "props")
            .Add(Expression.InsensitiveLike("props.Value", query, MatchMode.Anywhere))
            .List<Ad>();
    }
```

Hope it helps someone :-)